# Add start button to countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, countdowntimer, buttonclick

I added a start button to my countdown timer but It doesn't work. When I run it, it says that start is not defined. I inspected the code, and my console is printing out the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick". In my code above, I added the start function that will start my countdown timer. Could you tell me what I am missing? I look at other examples and I am still not able to make it work.

```js
 function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
   'total': t,
   'days': days,
   'hours': hours,
   'minutes': minutes,
   'seconds': seconds
  };
 }

 function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
   var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

   daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
   hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
   minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
   secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

   if (t.total <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
   }
  }

  updateClock();

  function start(){
   var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
  }
 }

 var deadline = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25");

 //var deadline = new Date($scope.data.deadLine); //new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
 initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00BF96;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00816A;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
  <div id="clockdiv">
    <div>
      <span class="days"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="hours"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="seconds"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button type="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: I think your problem might be because function start is inside of another function, so it is not known to the entire window, you should revise your design to make sure can start it outside of the function.

Comment: @ShohamBenShitrit I put it outside but still not working.

Comment: I found that I need to use declare my start function as start.onclick = function(){}.

Answer (score 0):

you have use start function inside **initializeClock** function if you want to continue with same code, you have to change some minor change in your code as following below.

```
<div>
 <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
 <div id="clockdiv">
   <div>
      <span class="days"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span class="hours"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
   </div>
<div>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
  <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
</div>
```

Start
Stop

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var timeinterval;
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
    var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
    var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
    var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

    function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
    }

    updateClock();

    this.start = function(){
        timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
    this.stop = function(){
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
}

var deadline = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25");
var init = new initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```